# c# Delegates, Events and Lambda Expr for new students

Tags: c#, events, delegates, lambda

I've been asked by my pointy haired boss to educate our new co-ops (interns) in the ways of C#. I have roughly ~30mins to cover the topics of Delegates, Events and Lambda Expressions. The time restriction is rather tight and the topics are broad. Since I'm not a C# guru, I would like some hints and pointers.

1. Since my time is short, what points should I cover with respect to the three topics listed above?
2. What are some good Do's and Dont's when using those three things?
3. I might have time for a short Lambda Expr demo. What is the most common use of LExpr (probably a Select().Where() statement on an enumerable??) that I could demo?

Thanks.

EDIT: The students have working knowledge of C++ and Java.

Comment: 30 minutes?  Good luck.  Not nearly enough time to breach either of those topics and their limitless possibilities.

Comment: Read them C# Skimming The Surface, the cliff's notes *to the cliff's notes* of Jon Skeet's C# In Depth. The latter title (the real book) would actually be quite helpful in showing the progression of the language from delegates to lambda expressions, but you hardly have enough time to go into any useful detail.

Comment: I'm trying to inform them so that they know that these things exist. If the students want to use them, they can hit MSDN for documentation or ask here with the nitty gritty details.

Comment: [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/events.aspx) may help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your boss is *serious* about this, at least ask to do **one 30 minute session per topic**. That will give you time to present it (very briefly), give them a quick demo and perhaps answer a few questions. After that, they should be given some time to play (or give them homework ;)).

How long do you have to prepare for this? As mentioned by [Anthony Pegram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/414076/anthony-pegram)'s comment, you would do well to introduce these topics through [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s book [C# In Depth, 2nd Edition](http://www.manning.com/skeet2/). You could always get the ebook if you don't have time to get the hard copy (I'd recommend getting the hard copy because it is a great reference book and a coupon for a free version of the ebook is included).

In the book he covers the evolution of C#. For example, he covers the evolution from explicit delegates to inline delegate actions with anonymous methods to lambda expressions as delegates (part of the evolution to make LINQ a reality).

I would recommend reading the following:

- chapter 2

  - section 2.1 (Delegates - C#1...base foundation knowledge of what they are).
  - In sub-section 2.1.3 he covers events (and the misconeption that events and delegates are the same thing).
- Chapter 5

  - sections 5.1 through 5.6
  - In section 5.4 he introduces inline delegates and anonymous functions. This is a good precursor to lambda expressions.
- Chapter 9

  - section 9.1 talks about lambda expressions as delegates.

Of course, if you are not able to get a copy of this book or don't have enough time to prepare (good luck!), then [here is a great article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/event_fundamentals.aspx) that is on par with Jon's book. It is quite lengthy, but covers everything you need. It's very clearly written and has good code samples. You may be able to preview this, then present it to your interns.

Answer (score 1):

As @Shark pointed out, it's not nearly enough time. All you can do is hit the highlights and point them towards resources.

I would use [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) for the demo and encourage the audience to download and experiment with the free tool. It includes many samples.

Suggest that the company purchase [LINQ Pocket References](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596519249) for everyone. It's $10 (per copy) well spent.

For the LINQ demo, I'd stick to one syntax - either Query Comprehension or Fluent, whichever you are most comfortable with. (Fluent is a better fit for demonstrating lambda expressions.) Use LINQ to Objects; just mention there are other providers. Again, check out the samples that come with LINQPad. "Chaining Query Operators" might be a good choice - Where, OrderBy, and Select on a string array.

Compare delegates to what they already know. Multicast aside, they're more-or-less function pointers.

Skip talking about anonymous delegates entirely, and go straight to lambda expressions. The syntax is shorter.

Be sure to mention the `Func<T>` family of generic delegates. These are very handy as predicates and factories.

Also suggest that they read [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

For events, stress the [.NET guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx). In particular, stress making a temporary copy of the event in the raising method to avoid a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

Some examples on Delegates and Lambda expr. good luck :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx